# Proguard complaining about duplicate definitions for com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo

Tags: android, apk, proguard, datanucleus, google-eclipse-plugin

I am getting an error from Proguard that I have never gotten before. And I hope someone here can help me because I am at a loss.

For some background: I just updated my Google Eclipse Plugin and DataNucleus because I am using App-Engine Connected Android Project. I did the update yesterday because it was required (i.e. App-engine refused to generate my endpoint unless I updated). So right now I am trying to create an external signed APK to put on the Play Store. I go through the normal process, which I do pretty much every other day. But today I am getting the error trace below. Please, somebody help me. Any hints, any clues, anything. Again, I am doing nothing that I haven't always done. My app tests fine on real devices. I am now trying to create an apk for the app store.

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
 Note: there were 364 duplicate class definitions.
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find superclass or interface javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoDataStore: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.Query
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.JDOImplHelper
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.JDOImplHelper
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable$ObjectIdFieldConsumer
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable$ObjectIdFieldConsumer
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable$ObjectIdFieldSupplier
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable$ObjectIdFieldSupplier
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.JDOImplHelper
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable$ObjectIdFieldConsumer
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable$ObjectIdFieldConsumer
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable$ObjectIdFieldSupplier
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable$ObjectIdFieldSupplier
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.PersistenceManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.PersistenceCapable
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.spi.StateManager
 Warning: com.google.api.client.extensions.jdo.JdoDataStoreFactory$JdoValue: can't find referenced class javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable
       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 Warning: there were 97 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Comment: I have already tried the following separately `-injars lib/google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc.jar` and
`-libraryjars lib/google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc.jar`

Comment: All of those missing classes are in "javax.jdo" jdo-api.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try add the following to `proguard-project.txt`:

> `-dontwarn javax.jdo.**`